# Setting up emacs with autocomplete, python-mode, and rope

Tags: python, emacs, python-mode, rope

I have all of the above installed. Rope seems to work just fine but I get the error below when I try to run auto-complete:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: rope-completions
```

I can't figure this out for the life of me. Any suggestions where to look for this error would be great??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this blog](http://hide1713.wordpress.com/2009/01/30/setup-perfect-python-environment-in-emacs/), you need the latest development version of Rope and Ropemacs for emacs to have `rope-completions` defined.

Comment: That blog was also from 2009 which the current releases are from 2010 or newer so probably included in the stable releases. I have grabbed the repos and will give it a go to see if it changes anything.

Comment: Did it work? I'm having this same issue and downloading the latest versions does nothing for me.

Comment: Symbol's function definition is void: rope-before-save-actions; on Aquamac 23.3, python-mode 6.3, latest version of robe, robemacs,